# Website files not updating

Tags: caching, refresh, history, filezilla

I have a seemingly simple issue, but it's been driving me insane for the past few hours. My website does not update any made changes on any of my files, until about 30 minutes later.

I've tried both Safari and Chrome, cleared their history and caches, refreshed the page, and yet it loads the old files. In my ftp client (I'm using Filezilla) everything appears to be in order too: Directory listing gets logged as successful, and correctly shows the new file and date of modification. When I checked back about half an hour later, everything seemed to have updated everything perfectly... File permissions are ok, Firewall is ok, Connection speed is reasonable...

I have no idea what the problem is. The only thing that I can think of is that I'm currently in another country, so far away from my server, yet I've updated my sites before without any problems. Does anyone know of this issue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you changed any of your DNS settings in the past while?

Comment: @Manu Thanks for your reply! I haven't changed any settings though :/

Comment: Try `Private Browsing`.

Comment: Hmm have you checked on another computer?

Comment: Perhaps a CDN is delivering cached files from a computer that is closer to where you are. Look up "cachebusting" techniques such as renaming the file with a `myFile.js?*randomString*` on the end.

Comment: The only other device I have available currently is my iPhone, but it doesn't update there either. Private browsing didn't change anything either, unfortunately.

Comment: @Noumenon That sounds more advanced than anything I'm used to :) But I'll give it a try! Thanks for your input!